# How to troubleshoot ORA-02049 and lock problems in general with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, deadlock, ora-02049

I am getting ORA-02049 occasionally for some long-running and/or intensive transactions. There is seemingly no pattern to this, but it happens on a simple INSERT.

I have no clue how to get any sort of information out or Oracle, but there has to be a way? A log over locking or atleast a way to see current locks?

Comment: Metalink has a lot of information about all of the ORA- codes, which you should look at. Ultimately, if you are getting this error on a production environment, you should open a support request with Oracle.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because it's more of a guess, but do you see ORA-600 errors in the alert log for the remote database?  If so, you might be running into ITL (interested transaction list) deadlocks.  I'm only suspecting this because you mention intensive transaction activity.  This might be due to low INITRANS values used when creating the tables and indexes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One possible way might be to increase the `INIT.ORA` parameter for `distributed_lock_timeout` to a larger value. This would then give you a longer time to observe the `v$lock` table as the locks would last for longer.

To achieve automation of this, you can either

- Run an SQL job every 5-10 seconds that logs the values of `v$lock` or the query that sandos has given above into a table and then analyze it to see which session was causing the lock.
- Run a `STATSPACK` or an `AWR` Report. The sessions that got locked should show up with high elapsed time and hence can be identified.

`v$session` has 3 more columns `blocking_instance, blocking_session, blocking_session_status` that can be added to the query above to give a picture of what is getting locked.

Comment: This _seems_ to have helped, just increasing the value of distributed_lock_timeout to 300 seconds.  I guess I am overloading the machines I am testing this on.

Answer (score 8):

Use this query to determine possible blocking locks:

```
SELECT se.username,
       NULL,
       se.sid,
       DECODE( se.command,
               0, 'No command',
               1, 'CREATE TABLE',
               2, 'INSERT',
               3, 'SELECT',
               4, 'CREATE CLUSTER',
               5, 'ALTER CLUSTER',
               6, 'UPDATE',
               7, 'DELETE',
               8, 'DROP CLUSTER',
               9, 'CREATE INDEX',
               10, 'DROP INDEX',
               11, 'ALTER INDEX',
               12, 'DROP TABLE',
               13, 'CREATE SEQUENCE',
               14, 'ALTER SEQUENCE',
               15, 'ALTER TABLE',
               16, 'DROP SEQUENCE',
               17, 'GRANT',
               18, 'REVOKE',
               19, 'CREATE SYNONYM',
               20, 'DROP SYNONYM',
               21, 'CREATE VIEW',
               22, 'DROP VIEW',
               23, 'VALIDATE INDEX',
               24, 'CREATE PROCEDURE',
               25, 'ALTER PROCEDURE',
               26, 'LOCK TABLE',
               27, 'NO OPERATION',
               28, 'RENAME',
               29, 'COMMENT',
               30, 'AUDIT',
               31, 'NOAUDIT',
               32, 'CREATE DATABASE LINK',
               33, 'DROP DATABASE LINK',
               34, 'CREATE DATABASE',
               35, 'ALTER DATABASE',
               36, 'CREATE ROLLBACK SEGMENT',
               37, 'ALTER ROLLBACK SEGMENT',
               38, 'DROP ROLLBACK SEGMENT',
               39, 'CREATE TABLESPACE',
               40, 'ALTER TABLESPACE',
               41, 'DROP TABLESPACE',
               42, 'ALTER SESSION',
               43, 'ALTER USER',
               44, 'COMMIT',
               45, 'ROLLBACK',
               46, 'SAVEPOINT',
               47, 'PL/SQL EXECUTE',
               48, 'SET TRANSACTION', 
               49, 'ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOG',
               50, 'EXPLAIN',
               51, 'CREATE USER',
               52, 'CREATE ROLE',
               53, 'DROP USER',
               54, 'DROP ROLE',
               55, 'SET ROLE',
               56, 'CREATE SCHEMA',
               57, 'CREATE CONTROL FILE',
               58, 'ALTER TRACING',
               59, 'CREATE TRIGGER',
               60, 'ALTER TRIGGER',
               61, 'DROP TRIGGER',
               62, 'ANALYZE TABLE',
               63, 'ANALYZE INDEX',
               64, 'ANALYZE CLUSTER',
               65, 'CREATE PROFILE',
               67, 'DROP PROFILE',
               68, 'ALTER PROFILE',
               69, 'DROP PROCEDURE',
               70, 'ALTER RESOURCE COST',
               71, 'CREATE SNAPSHOT LOG',
               72, 'ALTER SNAPSHOT LOG',
               73, 'DROP SNAPSHOT LOG',
               74, 'CREATE SNAPSHOT',
               75, 'ALTER SNAPSHOT',
               76, 'DROP SNAPSHOT',
               79, 'ALTER ROLE',
               85, 'TRUNCATE TABLE',
               86, 'TRUNCATE CLUSTER',
               88, 'ALTER VIEW',
               91, 'CREATE FUNCTION',
               92, 'ALTER FUNCTION',
               93, 'DROP FUNCTION',
               94, 'CREATE PACKAGE',
               95, 'ALTER PACKAGE',
               96, 'DROP PACKAGE',
               97, 'CREATE PACKAGE BODY',
               98, 'ALTER PACKAGE BODY',
               99, 'DROP PACKAGE BODY',
         TO_CHAR(se.command) ) command,
       DECODE(lo.type,
         'MR', 'Media Recovery',
         'RT', 'Redo Thread',
         'UN', 'User Name',
         'TX', 'Transaction',
         'TM', 'DML',
         'UL', 'PL/SQL User Lock',
         'DX', 'Distributed Xaction',
         'CF', 'Control File',
         'IS', 'Instance State',
         'FS', 'File Set',
         'IR', 'Instance Recovery',
         'ST', 'Disk Space Transaction',
         'TS', 'Temp Segment',
         'IV', 'Library Cache Invalidation',
         'LS', 'Log Start or Switch',
         'RW', 'Row Wait',
         'SQ', 'Sequence Number',
         'TE', 'Extend Table',
         'TT', 'Temp Table',
         'JQ', 'Job Queue',
         lo.type) ltype,
       DECODE( lo.lmode, 
         0, 'NONE',           /* Mon Lock equivalent */
         1, 'Null Mode',      /* N */
         2, 'Row-S (SS)',     /* L */
         3, 'Row-X (SX)',     /* R */
         4, 'Share (S)',      /* S */
         5, 'S/Row-X (SSX)',  /* C */
         6, 'Excl (X)',       /* X */
         lo.lmode) lmode,
       DECODE( lo.request, 
         0, 'NONE',           /* Mon Lock equivalent */
         1, 'Null',           /* N */
         2, 'Row-S (SS)',     /* L */
         3, 'Row-X (SX)',     /* R */
         4, 'Share (S)',      /* S */
         5, 'S/Row-X (SSX)',  /* C */
         6, 'Excl (X)',       /* X */
         TO_CHAR(lo.request)) request,
       lo.ctime ctime,
       DECODE(lo.block,
         0, 'No Block',
         1, 'Blocking',
         2, 'Global',
         TO_CHAR(lo.block)) blkothr,
       'SYS' owner,
       ro.name image
  FROM v$lock lo,
       v$session se,
       v$transaction tr,
       v$rollname ro
 WHERE se.sid = lo.sid
   AND se.taddr = tr.addr(+)
   AND tr.xidusn = ro.usn(+)
 ORDER BY sid
```

Comment: This gives good info, but for some reason my locks never show up here. They dont seem to show up very often in a simple "select * from v$lock ;" either, so thats probably the problem.

Comment: `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Answer (score 3):

Try increasing the SHARED_POOL_SIZE value in init.ora . 
 If that fails try `ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL`

Also see [this](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=253780).

Answer (score 2):

Could it be a bitmap index causing the error as described [here](http://oracle-magic.blogspot.com/2007/07/how-we-solved-ora-02049-timeout.html)?

Comment: Nope, as far as I can see we are not using any bitmap indexes.

Comment: In our case, it was indeed the bitmap index that was causing the problem. There's a very simple update that intermittently was crashing into the ORA-02049 error. But the transaction we are using is in no way distributed.(it doesn;t contain any db links either). One of the updated columns had a bitmap index on it. We have only 2 possible distinct values in that column, so we removed that index. That really solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a silly problem.

We are using Entity Framework 6.0 (upgraded to 6.2, but no change), Oracle.ManagedDataAccess +EntityFramework 12.2.1100, .NET 4.5.

I was getting `ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock` with the following query:

```
update "schemaname"."tablename"
set "DUE_DATE" = :p0
where ("ID" = :p1)
```

(via EF context.Database.Log event). A really simple query, shouldn't have any issues.

Well, I was using the same login on the remote server, on my local debugger, and in Oracle SQL Developer. A co-worker pointed out I should kill all these multiple connections while debugging .... and it worked. So the solution in my case was not to connect to the database multiple times with the same login.