# ORA-02049 after many failed inserts

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, locking, dblink

Can you please help me to identify what's wrong. I have a table into which I perform a really big select insert from another table. the first table is from a dblink. After a few unsuccessful tries and tests (my query was wrong then) it started throwing the said ora and doesn't allow me to insert even a single row. I can select from there though and no data is lost. How can i start inserting there again?

Comment: (1). Please show us the select and insert. (2). Check the DB link - what does it say when you do  a simple select to this table over dblink.

Comment: I have changed the query over time. Now I can't even perform simple test queries like insert into table@link (id) values(100). Select works fine, I can see all the data (in the state before the insert). I tried to close and reopen the link with    alter session close database link <name>; - still same

Comment: Have you checked some solutions around here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506411/how-to-troubleshoot-ora-02049-and-lock-problems-in-general-with-oracle

Comment: I tried increasing ALTER SYSTEM SET distributed_lock_timeout=120 scope=spfile;
COMMIT;  i tried select * from v$session but can't identify my case. It has been going on for a day already, this error

Comment: Have you tried making sure all the prior sessions that used the DBLink were killed?

Comment: Yeah I resolved it by committing and killing and committinng and reloading and committing and killing and committing again

Comment: You provide no code and no actual error messages - in short, you provide no actual, actionable, diagnostic information.  How is anyone supposed to help?